# tkz-euclide labels are way off

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, tkz-euclide

Good evening,
I'm porting a textbook of mine into Latex. I discovered the tkz-euclide package, which should greatly benefit me in making and adjusting figures. The first few figures I made worked well, with labels showing up right where they should have. But then I started having a some problems! Part of my problem - I thought - is that I need to create an exercise set with two columns. But then I pulled out a single picture into a new document with no other formatting. After typing in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,2); \coordinate (B) at (0,0); \coordinate (C) at (2,0);
    \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
    \tkzLabelAngle(A,B,C) {$\gamma$}% C,B,A 
    \tkzLabelAngle(B,C,A) {$\beta$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output I received was this:

[image]

Obviously, I would like the Greek letters to be inside the triangle, not outside.

I realize there is a way to type their positioning in using normal tikz 
`\node [right] at (0,0) {$\gamma$}` but tkz-euclide *should* work more smoothly (especially with a few hundred figures to type in!). It's worth a shot to see what this community thinks, anyway.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1. Your code above doesn't run; you need to have `\usetkzobj{all}` in the preamble. 2. There's no need to include `tikz` in your packages since `tkz-euclide` loads it automatically. 3. Use the option `pos` to place the labels where you want: `\tkzLabelAngle[pos = .35](A,B,C) {$\gamma$};
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos = .65](B,C,A) {$\beta$};` looks ok to me. You can find the documentation [here](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/TKZdoc-euclide.pdf)

Comment: @DJP To the best of my knowledge one does no longer need to add  `\usetkzobj{all}`. In fact, it will give rise to an error in the latest distributions.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat OK; I'm running an older version of TeX. Does the comment about `pos` solve the problem in newer distributions?

Comment: @DJP The labels are still outside with `\tkzLabelAngle[pos = .35](A,B,C) {$\gamma$}    
 \tkzLabelAngle[pos = .65](B,C,A) {$\beta$}` on my updated TeXLive 2020 installation. (Note that after the `tkz-euclide` macros you do not need `;`.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Should I delete my comments? I can't run tkz-euclide on new TeX version to see how to fix the code.

Comment: @DJP I think the link to the manual is good. I personally do not use `tkz-euclide`, not because there is something wrong with it, there isn't, but just because I am lazy and have not yet encountered a situation which required more than Ti*k*Z and its standard libraries (*except* for 3d stuff) so I am hesitant reading another manual.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat The ability to get intersection points of a line with a circle is convenient. Know you want to look at it on page 96. OK, I'll leave comment up.

Comment: @DJP This can be done with the `intersections` library, too.

Comment: @DJP with version >3 no need to call `\usetkzobj{all}`. Angle (A,B,C) and angle (C,B,A) are not the same :  angle rentrant and angle saillant in French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a lot of inaccuracies

1) no need to call TikZ, tkz-euclide works above TikZ and he loads it.

2) No need to add ";" with tkz-euclide, only if you want to use macros from TikZ.

3) When you want to work with an angle you need to give the points with anticlockwise direction. A,B,C and C,B,A are not the same.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/2/A,0/0/B,2/0/C}
  \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
  \tkzLabelPoints(B,C)   \tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
  \tkzMarkAngles[mark=none,size=0.8](C,B,A A,C,B)
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](C,B,A) {$\gamma$}
  \tkzLabelAngle[pos=1](A,C,B) {$\beta$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now this is what I was looking for! I was able to quickly whip this together:
```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \tkzDefPoints{0/2/A,0/0/B,2/0/C}
 \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
 \tkzLabelPoints[right](C) \tkzLabelPoints[left](A,B)
 \tkzLabelSegment[left](A,B) {2} \tkzLabelSegment[below](B,C) {2}
 \tkzLabelSegment(A,C) {$2\sqrt{2}$}
 \tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C)
 \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](B,A,C) {$\gamma$} \tkzLabelAngle[pos=.5](A,C,B) {$\alpha$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```
and produce [a picture it won't let me show :/ ]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a plain Ti*k*Z version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,2) coordinate (A) -- (0,0) coordinate (B) -- (2,0) coordinate (C)
     -- cycle;
    \draw[angle radius=7mm] pic ["$\gamma$", draw] {angle=C--B--A}
     pic ["$\beta$", draw,angle eccentricity=0.75] {angle=A--C--B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for this less verbose code.

Comment: This works; however, it doesn't work uniformly for all triangles. I found myself unhappy with where the labels showed up in other triangles, even after tweaking the angle eccentricity. It seems I should just go back to using nodes - I can get the labels precisely where I want them (at the cost of time). Surely there must be a more uniform and efficient way for labeling triangles?

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution only for fun purposes.

The following template is self-explanatory.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset
{
    PointSymbol=none,
    PointName=none,
    MarkAngleRadius=1.5,% don't append unit here!
    LabelSep=1,% don't append unit here!
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,8)
    \pstTriangle(1,1){A}(5,1){B}(1,7){C}
    \pstMarkAngle{C}{B}{A}{$\beta$}
    \pstRightAngle{B}{A}{C}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]